# Adobe recommends not to use DataGrid for MobileDevice profile

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mobile

I want to display sharedObject's data inside a `DataGrid` but I saw in the [online documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html) that "Adobe recommends that you not use this component in an application that uses the mobileDevice profile.". So what are the alternatives for DataGrid in mobile-flex ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your documentation reference is a bit outdated. Flex has since moved to the Apache community and is no longer property of Adobe.

And lucky for you one of the consequences of this move is that some company (can't remember which one) was kind enough to donate its mobile version of DataGrid to the Apache Flex project.

Here are the docs: https://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/MobileGrid.html
It's still marked as experimental, but since this comes from a company you know that it has been used in production already. I did some preliminary tests with it and it worked as expected.

You'll have to install Apache Flex 4.11 to use this component. Just got to http://flex.apache.org/installer.html and use the installer app.